# Connecting Eclipse to SVN server only when needed

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have installed SVN server on my Synology NAS and have successfully connected my Eclipse Java project to it.

However, I do not want to have the NAS online all the time.

I have not been able to see how I can get the SubVersive Eclipse plugin to connect to SVN "on demand" only.

Is this possible ?
Is it "safe" for me to work like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion already works in this way. It's designed to work in an "offline" mode, only communicating with the server when performing checkouts, commits, locks, updates, looking at logs, etc. If you're not performing an operation which requires data from the server, the client doesn't attempt to contact the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @alroc. However, when I restart eclipse and the NAS is off, eclipse complains and says the project has been removed from SVN.  I then close eclipse, startup the NAS and restart eclipse. At this point eclipse DOES NOT reconnect the project to SVN.  Is there a known workaround for this ?

Comment: There should be no reason for Eclipse to connect to your server after restarting unless you've intentionally configured it to attempt to do so (does it have such an option?). Is is possible that you've put some artifacts of the project which should be local onto your NAS?

Comment: I could not find any configuration for connecting at start up or not. What I did find, though, was that there are two eclipse plugins for SVN - SubVersive and Subclipse. The first is the one I had installed and, after some searching, has limitations. So I replaced it with Subclipse and everything works great. No problem when the server is offline and reconnects when it is online again just great. Thanks for your help